# Is this a good approach for android fade animation?

Tags: android

I'm just starting out with android development and I want to implement an ImageView which fades out, changes the image and fades back in. This snippet of code is working as intended right now, but I'm curious if it's a good approach to the problem.

```
(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000);
                    }
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Log.i("Ooopsie","Hey...Uhm i was kinda interrupted");
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(bart){
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.homer));
                        }else{
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bart));
                        }
                        bart=!bart;
                        imageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Rather than creating threads and using sleep, why not use a start delay, `imageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000).setStartDelay(1000)`?  The final image change can be done in an on complete listener.

Comment: I agree with user650881. Start delay is better for this task.

Comment: So...
I've tried just to get the animation right to run
`
imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000);
imageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000).setStartDelay(1000);
`
 but it does't seem to change anything